# Sci-fi book about a genetically modified planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, genetic-engineering

I read only the beginning of this book, and it was decades ago, but I always wondered about it and wanted to read it. As I recall, the protagonist finds himself stranded on a strange world. I don't remember how he got there, such as whether his spaceship crashed, or he just woke up there with amnesia, or whatever. But as he explored the world, the plants seemed to be a sort of mix between biological and technological.  Regarding the technological nature of the plants, I really don't remember the details. If I remember correctly, it was as if the plants had been somehow designed to be useful in some way.

Comment: Well, I read this book (or really just the beginning of it) in the early 90s or so. The book itself could have been older than that, but probably not more than few decades itself.

Comment: Can you clarify: was it a novel or an anthology (so, short-story)? Do you remember any more details--e.g. characters, planets, etc names. What about the plants was "technological"?

Comment: It was a novel. The only character I remember was the main character, who (if I remember correctly) was lost alone on the world.

Regarding the technological nature of the plants, I really don't remember the details. If I remember correctly, it was as if the plants had been somehow designed to be useful in some way. It was so long ago that I don't quite remember the specifics of their designed, technological aspect.

Comment: I've edited that detail into the question.

Comment: Was the main character in power armor initially? Was he transformed by the world? If so, how did it change him?

Comment: *"the plants seemed to be a sort of mix between biological and technological"* makes it sound like the plants are some kind of cyborg, but I guess you're just saying that they appear to be designed rather than evolved.

Comment: Greg Bear's *Legacy* has an ecosystem that kind of fits your description, but the protagonist Olmy isn't exactly stranded on the planet, he's there to investigate it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, they do appear to be designed rather than evolved.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I don't think he was in power armor, but just a spacesuit. I didn't read enough to know if he was transformed by the world, later in the book.

Comment: It is not Greg Bear's *Legacy." The protagonist in the book I am looking for was alone, at least during the beginning of the story, which is the only part I read at the time.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [*Sentenced To Prism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentenced_to_Prism) by Alan Dean Foster (1985).

From Wikipedia:

> Prism is a unique planet because its ecosystem contains both silicon-based and carbon-based life. Evan Orgell, a management troubleshooter sent to Prism to investigate the disappearance of a research group, finds himself fighting for his survival in this strange crystalline environment after his specialized environment suit succumbs to the local elements.

Comment: I looked this book up on Wikipedia, and don't think this is it. I don't remember crystalline environment at all. I seem to recall the plants sort of looked somewhat familiar to what we would find on Earth, and that it was only on closer inspection that the impression that they had been designed in some way became apparent.